# Differences between two models

Tags: c#

Is there a way to compare 2 models and only show the differences, for example what has been updated, added or deleted?

For example, in the models below, I have created a number of `Sample` models:

```
var grocers1 = new List<Grocer>();

var grocer1 = new Grocer
{
    Id = 1,
    Expenditure = 500,
    Name = "Bob"
};

grocers1.Add(grocer1);

var grocers2 = new List<Grocer>();

var grocer2 = new Grocer
{
    Id = 1,
    Expenditure = 300,
    Name = "Bob"
};

grocers2.Add(grocer2);

var fruits = new List<Fruit>();

var fruit1 = new Fruit();

fruits.Add(fruit1);

var orders1 = new List<Order>();

var order1 = new Order
{
    Id = 1,
    SampleId = 1,
    Fruits = fruits
};

var order2 = new Order
{
    Id = 1,
    SampleId = 1,
    Fruits = fruits
};

orders1.Add(order1);
orders1.Add(order2);

var orders2 = new List<Models.Documents.Order> {order1};

var sample = new Sample
{
    Id = 1,
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-10-23"),
    Grocers = grocers1,
    Orders = orders1
};

var changedSample = new Sample
{
    Id = 1,
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-10-22"),
    Grocers = grocers2,
    Orders = orders1
};

var otherChangedSample = new Sample
{
    Id = 1,
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-10-23"),
    Grocers = grocers1,
    Orders = orders2
};
```

So if I compare `sample` to `changedSample` it should just show the Date has changed from 2018-10-23 to 2018-10-22 and that the Expenditure has changed from 500 to 300.

Then if I was to compare `sample` to `otherChangedSample` it should show that `order2` has been removed.

And then finally if I was to compare `otherChangedSample` to `sample` it would show that order 2 had been added.

I have tested with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data) this is great for comparing the same base model, excluding lists, it nicely highlights the changes.

I then tried [Compare-Net-Objects](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) which is good, this time does take into account lists and highlights the changes, but only if the list count stays the same. It will identify the list count change but not tell you the values of what has been removed or the values of what has been added.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compare-Net-Objects comes very close to what you need. My advice to you would be to fork the project and modify it to suit your needs. It shouldn't be hard to modify it to compare lists with differing counts.

Comment: I agree Compare-Net-Objects does come very close, but even with IgnoreCollectionOrder set to true, it doesn't quite do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection and extension method as well:

```
var sample = new Sample
{
    Id = 1,
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-10-23"),
    Grocers = grocers1,
    Orders = orders1
};

var otherChangedSample = new Sample
{
    Id = 1,
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-10-23"),
    Grocers = grocers1,
    Orders = orders2
};

class Variance
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public object valA { get; set; }
    public object valB { get; set; }
}
List<Variance> rt = sample.DetailedCompare(otherChangedSample);
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

static class extentions
{
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            Variance v = new Variance();
            v.Prop = f.Name;
            v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
            v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
            if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                variances.Add(v);

        }
        return variances;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however if I run the code you have suggested I get `{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}` for the variable `fi` and therefore does not loop through the fi array.

Comment: check what is the type of val1 and see that you have the correct type passed.

Comment: @iggyweb perhaps you need some [BindingFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netstandard-1.6) for GetFields, for instance `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public`

Comment: `val1` is `sample` and `val2` is `otherChangedSample` as per your code.

Comment: Check with @Default's comment, if the values are correct, you should see the fields.

Comment: If I change the line `FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();` to `FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);` I still get `{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}` for the variable `fi`.

Answer (score 0):

have you coded your model classes yourself? If not, then you have to deal with reflection (could be slow and you have to do a lot of programming to cover all data types), or with serialization (serialize as string and do a string compare).

If you can extend your classes, then I would add a method to every single class:

```
internal void TrackChange(T other, List<Change> changes)
```

This method in your class `Sampe` would look like:

```
void TrackChange(Sample other, List<Change> changes)
{
    if (this.Id != other.Id) changes.add(new Change(...));
    if (this.Date != other.Date) changes.add(new Change(...));
    if (this.Grocers.count != other.Grocers.count) changes.add(new Change(...)); // number of items has changed
    for (int i = 0; i < math.min(this.grocers.count, other.grocers.count); i++)
        this.grocers[i].TrackChange(other.grocers[i], changes);
    ....
}
```

The `Grocer` class has its onwn TrackChange method. and so on.

This is some coding, but the most efficient and you can handle all cases yourself. for example if the order of grocers in your list does not mind, then you can iterate all grocers of this list and try to find the corresponding grocer in the others list (e.g. by Id) and call the TrackChange then.

Comment: These are just examples to demonstrate the issue I am facing. I believe AutoMapper uses reflection, which only addresses the base model as the model properties are constant, lists can be dynamic, which is where I am encountering difficulty.

Comment: my experience with reflection is that there are a lot of situations and constellations you have to face. for example the simple `valA.Equals(valB)` depends if the valA is a ValueType of if valA is a referenceType. if a referenceType and not a string, then for valA has to be compared recursively for all properties. And there are fields and properties to handle, except a field is only a backing field for a property, .... I always ended up to code the comparision myself if I have access to the code.